# Material UI Toggle Button border doesn't visible

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui, togglebutton

The border line on the left does not appear in the toggle bar below that I prepared with MuiToggleButton. what could be the reason, thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hkuw.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAnH6.png)

note : it works correctly in hover state

```
1. const ToggleButton = styled(MuiToggleButton)({
  '&.MuiToggleButton-root': {},
  '&.Mui-selected:hover': {
    color: '#10B981',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: '#10B981',
  },
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    color: '#10B981',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: '#10B981',
  },
});
```

In the selected state, the left border is not visible.
border : "1px solid red",
but the left side is not visible.

Comment: I think the border is showing but is hidden behind the other border because they are stacking on top of one another. Try adding a z-index rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround by giving the following border value to the sx probe of the 1st button.

```
 sx={{
          borderRight: '1px solid',
          borderRightColor: 'green',
        }}
```